# Vanilla JS Countdown Timer Automatically Runs

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a pomodoro timer and I'm in the process of adding a button to start/stop but I'm trying to have my timer not automatically start upon page refresh.

```
var timer = 1500;
var secondsRemaining;
var interval = setInterval(myTimer,1000);

function convertSeconds(timer)
{
var min = Math.floor (timer / 60);
var sec = timer - (min * 60);

//add a leading zero (as a string value) if seconds less than 10
if (sec < 10) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }
return min + ':' + sec;
}

//
function myTimer()                         
{
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = convertSeconds(timer);
timer--; 
if (timer < 0)                        
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

https://codepen.io/powershell19/pen/vYNbeZy

Comment: then don't put `setInterval(myTimer,1000);` in the top level... put it in the button handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. Click play button.

```js
var timer = 1500;
var secondsRemaining;
var interval;

function convertSeconds(timer) {
  var min = Math.floor(timer / 60);
  var sec = timer - (min * 60);

  //add a leading zero (as a string value) if seconds less than 10
  if (sec < 10) {
    sec = "0" + sec;
  }
  return min + ':' + sec;
}

//
function myTimer() {
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = convertSeconds(timer);
  timer--;
  if (timer < 0)
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

p {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
}

#timer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-30%);
  font-size: 7em;
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: black;
}

#logo {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  transform: translateY(-20%);
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Box */

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 506px;
  height: 360px;
  top: 71px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 31px;
}

.fa-play {
  font-size: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 83px;
  height: 77px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 265px;
}

.fa-pause {
  font-size: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 83px;
  height: 77px;
  left: 270px;
  top: 265px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p id="logo">FocusTimer</p>
    <div id="timer">
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-play" onclick="setInterval(myTimer,1000);"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-pause"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the interval until the user clicks the "Start" button.

Something like...

```js
var timer = 1500;
var secondsRemaining;
var interval;  // <= declared, not initialized

function convertSeconds(timer)
{
var min = Math.floor (timer / 60);
var sec = timer - (min * 60);

//add a leading zero (as a string value) if seconds less than 10
if (sec < 10) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }
return min + ':' + sec;
}

//
function myTimer()                         
{
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = convertSeconds(timer);
timer--; 
if (timer < 0)                        
  clearInterval(interval);
}

// call this function from "onclick" event handler of button
function startTimer()
{
    interval = setInterval(myTimer, 1000)
}
```